# I just overwrote my folder while mounting a hard disk drive. How do I undo/recover it?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, mount

I was trying to mount a Linux filesystem on a Mac and accidentally mounted it to my `~/Documents` folder using a utility [ext4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse).

Below command is the issued command:

```
sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk2s7 ~/Documents
```

And after that, I can't access my `~/Documents` folder. Is it there or gone forever?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the files are still there, you just can't get at them since the mount point has changed the system's ability to resolve files in /Users/whatever (a.k.a.~)

Going forward, try mounting the drive under /Volumes (as in `sudo ext4fuse /dev/disk2s7 /Volumes/myDrive`)

You should probably reboot the Mac since many programs will have issues saving work to the home folder. If you are working on some important documents, maybe save them to /Users/Shared if you wish, but hopefully you have a good backup system in case this messed things up more than expected.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac. Does rebooting automatically unmount drives?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Yes - this manual mount command doesn't write a command to mount it forevermore it's just a one time event.

Comment: Reboot, really? Why not just unmount?